# How to interpret $\prod_{i=0}^0 1-t^{4i-8}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, notation

How to interpret $\prod_{i=0}^0 1-t^{4i-8}$?

Would this equal $1$ or $1 - t^{-8}$?

Comment: It is $1-t^{-8}$.

Comment: It is not an empty product since there is in fact a valid value of $i$ in the range $0\leq i\leq 0$, that value being $i=0$.  So, the "product" has just one term in it, that term being $1-t^{-8}$

Comment: Assuming what you have written is not $\prod_{k=0}^{0} 1 - t^{-8+4i}$, where the exponent of $t$ is the complex number $-8 + 4i$ and your question is not about notation confusion, what others have commented here is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) off-by-one error: if $A,\,B$ are integers with $A\le B$ then $A\le i\le B$ has $B-A\color{blue}{+1}$ solutions. So as @QiZhu & @JMoravitz noted, you need the $i=0$ factor, giving $1-t^{-8}$.